# Create objects from main key and value from nested object

Tags: javascript

I'll keep it simple. Suppose I have an object like this:

```
  let myObj = {
    name:{
      value: "John",
      type: "contains"  
    },
    age:{
      value: "5",
      type: "contains"  
    }
  }
```

how can I create a new object that contains the main key but the value is just the `value` of its nested object, as follows:

```
  let myNewObj = {
    name: "John",
    age: "5"
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can the values also be objects like this?

Comment: `Object.keys(myObj).reduce((o, k) => ({ ...o, [k]: myObj[k].value }), {})` or plain iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to extract the `value` key for each object, you can do something like this:

```js
let myObj = {
  name:{
    value: "John",
    type: "contains"  
  },
  age:{
    value: "5",
    type: "contains"  
  }
}
  

let newObj = {}

for (const key in myObj) {
    newObj[key] = myObj[key].value;
}

console.log(newObj);
// {
//   age: "5",
//   name: "John"
// }
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the object to its entries array and map through it to return `[key,value]`
Then convert to a new object using `Object.fromEntries`

```js
  let myObj = {
    name:{
      value: "John",
      type: "contains"  
    },
    age:{
      value: "5",
      type: "contains"  
    }
  }
  
  let myNewObj = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(myObj).map(([key,{value}])=>[key,value]))
  console.log(myNewObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, to be able to transform all the values of an object's properties according to a mapping function, you can use `Object.entries` to make an array of `[key, value]` arrays for each property, and then use `Object.fromEntries` to reconstitute an object from those arrays.  You can provide a generic transformation function in the middle of that operation like this:

```
const transformValues = (obj, transform) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => [key, transform(value)]));
```

The transform function you need in your specific case will take the property value (which is an object) and just return its `value` property. Like this: `({ value }) => value` (*This is pretty easy with destructuring.*)

```js
let myObj = {
  name: {
    value: "John",
    type: "contains"
  },
  age: {
    value: "5",
    type: "contains"
  }
}

const transformValues = (obj, transform) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => [key, transform(value)]));

const result = transformValues(myObj, ({ value }) => value);

console.log(result);
```